# jQuery: show new fields in a list

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show a new fields up to a max of 10 each time a button is pressed.

I currently only have:

```
$('.add_field').live('click', function(){
    $(this).next('.field1').fadeIn();
    return false;
});
```

HTML:

```
 <fieldset>
     <label>Label Name</label>
     <input id="field1" name="field1" type="text">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
     <label>Label Name</label>
     <input id="field2" name="field2" type="text">
</fieldset>
...
<a class="add_field" href="#">Add Field</a>
```

I don't need to dynamically add the fields just show them, they are all in the HTML just hidden. I'm not sure how to show just the next field in the list on each button press. Each of these fields has unique number but I'm unsure on how to up the count on each button press to show them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please add your HTML as well

Comment: @Alexander Didn't know what that was. Did it now.

Answer (score 2):

With the posted HTML - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pPbv2/)

```
$('.add_field').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('fieldset:hidden').eq(0).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Zoltan. And to remove a field I'm guessing it would be very similiar. Replace :hidden with :default and .fadeIn() with .fadeOut ?

Comment: there is no `:default` - it's `:visible`

Comment: a quick demo of that http://jsfiddle.net/pPbv2/1/  or if you want to delete the fields from the bottom first http://jsfiddle.net/pPbv2/2/

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATED

This is an updated version of my code that fits your recently posted HTML layout. The idea keeps being the same: on click find the first hidden element and show it.

```
$('.add_field').click(function(evt){
  $("fieldset:hidden:eq(0)").fadeIn();
  evt.preventDefault();
});
```

---

### PREVIOUS

You can use a combination of the [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector and [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).

```
$('.add_field').click(function(evt){
  $(this).nextAll(':hidden').eq(0).fadeIn();
  evt.preventDefault();
});
```

As long as such hidden next sibling exist.